# Setting encoding in XML files

Tags: xml, encoding

Which are the valid xml encoding strings? For instance, what is the way of specifying UTF-8:

- `encoding="utf8"`
- `encoding="utf8"`
- etc

Or Windows 1251:

- `encoding="windows-1251"`
- `encoding="windows1251"`
- `encoding="cp-1251"`
- etc.

I am making a character decoder as well as a xml parser. Thus, I need to be able to set the encoding of my StreamReader based on the value from the encoding attribute.

Any ideas where I could find a list of the official encoding string?

The best I could find is [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752010.aspx), but it seems to be IE specific.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd be very interested to know why you are writing your own XML parser. Any reason you don't use an existing parser?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If all fails, read the spec :-).

> 4.3.3 Character Encoding in Entities
>
> Each external parsed entity in an XML
>   document may use a different encoding
>   for its characters.
>
> [...]
>
> In an encoding declaration, the values
>   " UTF-8 ", " UTF-16 ", "
>   ISO-10646-UCS-2 ", and "
>   ISO-10646-UCS-4 " SHOULD be used for
>   the various encodings and
>   transformations of Unicode / ISO/IEC
>   10646, the values " ISO-8859-1 ", "
>   ISO-8859-2 ", ... " ISO-8859- n "
>   (where n is the part number) SHOULD be
>   used for the parts of ISO 8859, and
>   the values " ISO-2022-JP ", "
>   Shift_JIS ", and " EUC-JP " SHOULD be
>   used for the various encoded forms of
>   JIS X-0208-1997.
>
> It is RECOMMENDED
>   that character encodings registered
>   (as charsets) with the Internet
>   Assigned Numbers Authority
>   [IANA-CHARSETS](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#IANA), other than those just
>   listed, be referred to using their
>   registered names; other encodings
>   SHOULD use names starting with an "x-"
>   prefix.

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/

So UTF-8 is written as `encoding="UTF-8"`.

For other character sets not listed above, use the names given in the [IANA character set list](http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets).

Case of the letters in the character set name is not significant: "However, no distinction is made
between use of upper and lower case letters." (IANA character set list). So you could also write
`encoding="uTf-8"` if you feel like it ;-).

BTW: Are you really, *really* certain you want to write your own XML parser? This sounds suspiciously like reinventing the wheel.

Comment: +1 for 'read the spec', -1 for 'if all fails' (it should be the first port of call when writing a parser, not the last) and +1 again for 'reinventing the wheel' ;)

Comment: @David Dorward Thanks :-). To be honest, in generally I would not recommend the spec as first port of call to a beginner, many specs can be rather daunting. But the spec is the place to go if you can't find the answer in a tutorial (or if you want to be certain what is right). Anyway, you probably noted the smiley next to "if all fails".

Comment: The smiley is next to *read the spec* :) Seriously though, the question suggests the goal is to write a general parser, so it needs to cover everything that it might be parsing, and that really *really* needs the spec as it lays out the requirements in technical terms. I'd be very surprised if anybody wrote documentation that provided enough information to write a parser that was aimed at beginners.

Comment: As *sleske* said, it all goes to the IANA list: http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets Thanks a lot! I've been stupid not to find this in the spec. Yes, I need my own parser for some embarrassing reasons. Thanks, again!

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

should be fine for utf-8.

Answer (score 0):

Use command locale -A to see all the encodings:
http://dwbitechguru.blogspot.ca/2014/07/check-foreign-characters-support-on.html

Option A:
To add encoding using the below tags:

You can edit the encoding attribute in the the dtd using XML spy.

Related links:
http://dwbitechguru.blogspot.ca/2014/07/issue-xml-reader-error.html

Comment: Put a few more spaces before your XML to get it to format properly.