# Is encoding Cp1252 invalid in an XML file?

Tags: java, xml, encoding

Some XML file I ran across is failing a well-formed XML check, even though it looks well-formed to me (I might be wrong.)

I have reduced it to a trivial example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Cp1252"?>
<jnlp/>
```

The method being used to do the check works like this:

```
public static boolean isWellFormedXml(InputStream inputStream) {
    try {
        XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        inputFactory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_COALESCING, false);
        inputFactory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.SUPPORT_DTD, false);
        XMLStreamReader reader = inputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(stream);
        try {
            // Scan through all the reader tokens to ensure everything is well formed
            while (reader.hasNext()) {
                reader.next();
            }
        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }
    } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
        // Ignore the exception
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The error I'm seeing is:

```
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,40]
```

Message: Invalid encoding name "Cp1252".

Only problem is - I can breakpoint at the catch and confirm that this encoding name *does* resolve. So what's the deal here? Does XML also restrict which encodings you're allowed to use in the prologue?

Comment: i found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967115/setting-encoding-in-xml-files

Answer (score 4):

check:

http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xml

i guess the encoding you're looking for COULD be windows-1252. Cp1252 might be a valid charset in java, but in XML, you're not supposed to use it (by that name).

Comment: I know that windows-1252 is the standard name for the charset and if I wrote an XML file I wouldn't have used a Windows charset at all (I always use UTF-8.) But we're just trying to parse existing files, not writing new XML files to parse. :)

Comment: hmm ... if everything fails - and you know the source of your xml files & you can't change it ... maybe you want to pre-process those files? seems ugly, i know ...

Comment: correct link is (probably due to changes over the years): http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets